# Why did you delete my comment/question

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers

[Transfer cell value to another cell by clicking on a button in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29312/transfer-cell-values-to-another-cell-by-clicking-on-button-google-spreadsheet/31528#31528)

I need help with understanding the code - why delete it?

Answer (score 7):

You posted a comment as an answer -

[image]

Stack Exchange is not a forum, it's a Q&A site and we try to ensure that answers section contains *only* answers, not comments or additional questions.

Commenting on others' post requires 50 reputation, which you don't have and hence add a comment is not available for you.

If you have a question, you'll need to ask a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Please ensure you add all relevant details before posting a question though.

Answer (score 5):

Underneath questions is the place for answers to the problem. That your post was asking for help means that you were not posting an answer and due to content cleaning, was deleted on that ground.

If you need help with something then you need to post a fresh question. If it's related to a previous question, it wouldn't hurt to include that link for reference.